# Server Error in '/' Application.Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

[image]I tried to run this code and error pops out specific cast not valid. Before any LINQ was added is doing fine. Please, help thank you. Before any of the LINQ was added still fine. But now it couldn't load the User database context. I have no idea how this happened. Please send help thank you.

```
ForumDBDataContext db = new ForumDBDataContext();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
}

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string emailAddress = txtEmail.Text;
    string password = txtpwd.Text;
    bool rememberMe = chkRememberMe.Checked;

    User u = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(
                x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress &&
                x.Hash == Security.GetHash(password)
                );

    if (u != null)
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        var query = from m in db.Members
                    where m.EmailAddress == emailAddress
                    select m.Last_Login_Date;

        Convert.ToDateTime(currentDate);
        DateTime lld = Convert.ToDateTime(query);
        int diffDays = DateTime.Compare(currentDate, lld);


        if (diffDays > 72)
        {
            Response.Redirect("ChangePwd.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Security.LoginUser(u.Name, u.Role, rememberMe);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can not use `Security.GetHash`method in LINQ since this method can not be translated into SQL.

Comment: this code is done in c# and before this it could run. So I don't think the Security.GetHash is the problem

Comment: @HowToGame What does your `db.Users` look like?

Comment: CREATE VIEW [dbo].[User]
 AS 
 SELECT [Id],[EmailAddress],[Name],[Hash],[DateJoined], [Last_Login_Date],'Member' AS [Role]
 FROM [Member]

 UNION
 SELECT [Id],[EmailAddress],[Name],[Hash],[DateJoined],[Last_Login_Date], 'Admin' AS [Role]
 FROM [Admin]

Comment: i create a view to combine member and admin

Comment: @HowToGame Does your `View` return a `User` type? Can you show me your `User` model?

Comment: @HowToGame Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `Security.GetHashmethod` in LINQ since this method can not be translated into SQL. You need to run this method and set variable before run LINQ:

```
string emailAddress = txtEmail.Text;
string password = txtpwd.Text;
bool rememberMe = chkRememberMe.Checked;
var hashedPassword = Security.GetHash(password);

User u = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(
            x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress &&
            x.Hash == hashedPassword 
            );
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is type of `Hash` property of `User` ?

Comment: Hash is the encrypted password. User is the view of UNION Member and Admin.
Hash is char(54) and Inside User has Id,Email_Address,Username,Hash,Last_Date_Joined, Date_Joined,Profile_Picture

Comment: I mean is that type of `Int` or `String` etc?

Comment: have to put char due on different characters and integer

Comment: but I don't think that is the problem. Yesterday was still fine but now it can't process the UserDBContext. I literally have no idea what happened